# How can I divide a rectangular area into smaller rectangles that represent a percentage of the total area?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Basically I'm trying to get a "nice" image where all the small rectangles add up to the big rectangle, kind like:

[image: Disk Inventory X]

*Later Edit to clarify some things:

1. I want to be able to draw something like this in a piece of software. So, what I need is closer to an algorithm.
2. All I need are some rectangles. I don't need them to have some predefined proportions just that they look like a rectangle. Anything between a square and a 3:1 width/height (or height/width) is fine. The extremely naive approach would be to just divide the width of the enclosing rectangle into the percentage that enclosed rectangles have but this will create thin slices and some of the smaller percentage rectangles will drop bellow 1px.

I need to find a way to split the rectangles on multiple rows.

*Second Edit: **Problem SOLVED**. I was looking for a TreeMap algorithm (as pointed out by [Phpdna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340457/phpdna)). Once I had the keyword I was able to quickly find a couple of python implementations that satisfied my requirements.

Comment: Question somewhat unclear. Are you attempting to create a software algorithm for this? Is there a specific way you want the rectangles split up? Do you want to be able to specify in code or by user how to split it up? If so, what language are you using, and what have you tried? This actually looks to me like a question that belongs more so on http://math.stackexchange.com/ than here just because it seems to be a  math question more than a programming question by the way it's worded.

Comment: Depends on what you mean as a percentage. Do you want each box to mean a specific amount (i.e. 5%) or just divide the remaining space as efficiently as possible or have each rectangle be specific proportions (i.e. a 4:3 rectangle)?

Also, you may want to Look at the Fibannacci Spiral/Golden Spiral (same thing, 2 names) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral Your example is using some of its concepts (the bottom right hand corner is a dead giveaway)

Comment: @seren01 There's a lot of things wrong with this question, it belonging on [math.se] is **not** one of them. This is purely an algorithm (i.e. programming) question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem#Different_rectangles_in_a_rectangle ?

Comment: @Dukeling Alright, sorry bout that. I was just confused by this question.

Comment: You haven't explained why the rectangles in your sample output are chosen to be those sizes.  For example, if you want to divide your rectangle into n smaller rectangles, is it a valid solution to just divide it into n equally sized rectangles?  If not, you need to specify the constraints that would disqualify such a solution.

Comment: You really need to explain __exactly__ what you want in the way of rectangles.  There are an infinite amount of ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treemap is an algorithm that can pack smaller rectangles into a map. You can recursively subdivide a plane into smaller tiles for example by splitting the plane along the 2 axis and save the result to a tree.

Comment: This is what I was searching for. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This approach guarantees that the small rectangles always cover the initial rectangle.  so does any other approach which starts by constructing rectangles within an existing set of rectangles.

1. Draw a straight line from one edge of the plane to the opposite edge and parallel to the other two edges.  Draw it in a location which produces 2 rectangles whose proportions are pleasing to your eye.
2. If you want another rectangle, draw a line from the first line, perpendicular to it, and extend that line to the edge of the plane.  Again, choose its position so that the line creates rectangles of pleasing proportions.  Now you have 3 rectangles.
3. Now, to get the 4th rectangle, choose one of the existing lines to start from and draw a line perpendicular to it until it reaches either the edge of the plane or an existing line.  Again, take care to ensure that the proportions of the rectangles created are pleasing to your eye.
4. Continue until you have all the rectangles you want.

Personally I think that the above is the easy part, the difficult part is determining algorithmically where to draw the lines.  I suggest you think of [the Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), it cousins [the Fibonnaci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) and other ratios such as the basis of the A series of paper sizes, *ie* `1:sort(2)`.